# Idiomatic way of branching depending on the existance of a type evidence in Scala

Tags: scala, types, implicits

I find myself more than once writing the following ugly pattern:

```
class Something[A, B](implicit ev: A =:= B = null) {
  ...

  def doStuff {
    if (ev == null) ... // know that A is not the same as B
    else ...            // safely assume A is equal to B
  }
}
```

Even worse, when `ev != null`, I would sometimes write heresies such as `someB.asInstanceOf[A]`.

Comment: Why not just treat it the same way you should treat the possibility of `null` anywhere else (i.e. `Option(ev)`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a type class,

```
trait DoStuff[A, B] {
  def apply(): Unit
}

trait DoStuff0 {
  implicit def neDoStuff[A, B]: DoStuff[A, B] =
    new DoStuff[A, B] { def apply(): Unit = ... body of your ev == null case ...
}

object DoStuff extends DoStuff0 {
  implicit def eqDoStuff[A]: DoStuff[A, A] =
    new DoStuff[A, A] { def apply(): Unit = ... body of your ev != null case ...
}

class Something[A, B](implicit ds: DoStuff[A, B]) {
  ...
  def doStuff: Unit = ds()
}
```

Comment: Should this code 
<< trait Something[A, B](implicit ds: DoStuff[A, B]) {
  def doStuff: Unit = DoStuff()
} >>
change to 
<< class Something3[A, B] {
  def doStuff()(implicit ds: DoStuff[A, B]) : Unit = ds.doStuff
} >>

Comment: @Cloudtech it depends on the context but if, as here, the instance can be fixed once and for all when `Something` is instantiated, then why defer it and possibly pay the cost of summoning it each time the method is invoked?